# How to let music be played from receiver instead of loud-speaker?

Tags: android, audio, playback, speaker

(by saying receiver, i mean the part when you hear a phone call normally.)
somebody gave following code piece, which does not work. any help please?

```
  Object obj = new Object();
  Method method;
  try {
   method = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem").getMethod(
     "setDeviceConnectionState", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE,Integer.TYPE,
                                               String.class });
   method.invoke(obj, new Object[] {num,1,""});
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
  }

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  String type = getMIMEType(f);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), type);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What? A receiver doesn't play sound; that's why it's called a **receiver**. You speak into it. It doesn't speak to you.

Comment: Karl: A telephone receiver is the part you take off the hook to speak into *and* listen to -- at least since the 1940s.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```